# When does javascript convert a number to exponential notation? What is the breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers, dynamic-programming, palindrome

When does the Javascript automatically convert a number of `e` notation? For a modified Fibonacci sequence given as:

[image]

a function could be written as follows:

```
    function fibonacciModified(t1, t2, n) {
            const T = Array(n).fill(0);
            T[0] = t1;
            T[1] = t2;
            for(let i=2;i<T.length;i++) {
                T[i] = T[i-2] + Math.pow(T[i-1],2);
            }
            
            return T;
    }

    const T = fibonacciModified(0,1,10);
    console.log(T);
```

give an output which resembles as:

[image]

The last number of table `T`, the javascript decided to automatically convert this to `e` form. When does javascript do that? What is the trigger point? How could I convert this back to the normal form?

Comment: That would probably happen at some point when you're above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. I don't think it's useful to turn this into a "real" number anyway, as it's already going to be imprecise. Consider using BigInt

Comment: @VLAZ I am trying this in one of the online judge. How could I compensate for the size of the result? Any idea?

Comment: Use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s. Basically, `12` is a normal number, `12n` is a BigInt which will guarantee larger values are precise. To increase to power `12n ** 2n === 144n`

Comment: Before you actually push the value into the array, you could pass it to a function that changes the exponential form to normal integer like mentioned in http://blog.davidjs.com/2018/07/convert-exponential-numbers-to-decimal-in-javascript/

Comment: @GreenWizard 1. the number `8.426661309728124e22` is already very likely imprecise, due to the limited nature of IEE 754 number representation. 2. That suggestion just modifies the base number by the exponent which will lead to *further* precision loss. The number has 14 decimal digits shown and multiplying by 10^22 will lead to the last 8 digits be zeroes, instead of whatever they originally were.

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, all javascript numbers are effectively stored in scientific notation like that (they're stored as doubles). It's just the browser choosing to display the number in different ways when you ask it to show it to you. You can learn more about how javascript numbers are implemented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). I didn't find any good, authoritative sources on when browsers start to display numbers in scientific notation. I don't know if it's defined by a standard or if it's browser-dependent, but my browser (Chrome) starts doing it once the number has 22 digits.

If you wish to display a number in a different format, you can convert it to a string. [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) has a number of options to let you fine-toon how you want it to appear. For example:

```
> (1e25).toLocaleString('en-us', { useGrouping: false })
"10000000000000000000000000"
```

I will warn that the underlying implementation of numbers can only hold so much precision. When you start working with a lot of digits, you're going to lose some accuracy.

```
> 12345678901234567890
12345678901234567000
```

Numbers bigger than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (9007199254740991) may start to lose precision due to their finite binary representation. The way to avoid this is to use a different number type - the [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). BigInts store numbers in a different format that allow it to hold arbitrarily large integers. BigInt literals are created by simply putting an "n" after your number, and can be used in many ways similar to a normal number (including the ability to use .toString() or .toLocaleString())

```
> 12345678901234567890n
12345678901234567890n
> (12345678901234567890n).toString()
'12345678901234567890'
```